# Function within a function does not return expected value

Tags: linux, bash, function

My ultimate goal is to process a configuration file and add an entry at a specific place in the file, i.e. in a specific row.

As you'll see in the shell script listed below (run in **Linux** (SLES 11)), I use two functions:

1. `getLine` which returns the line where I want to add my entry
2. `UserEntry` which basically writes the entry in the specified line.

*(Any suggestions on another way to do this are welcome).*

The issue I am facing is that when I call `getLine` from within `UserEntry` (Method 1), `getLine` does not return any value. Basically the line just before `grep -q -v` is empty!

I have to call them separately from the main script (Method 2), i.e. first call `getLine` and then call `UserEntry` passing as parameter the value of the variable from `getLine`.

This way works, however it puzzles me why the first way doesn't.

These are the configuration file and the bash script:

### Configuration file `snmpd.cnf`

```
#
## SOME STUFF HERE
#
blablabla

# Entry type: usmUserEntry
# Format: usmUserEngineID  (octetString)
#         Normally localSnmpID.
#
#         SOME MORE STUFF HERE
#
# usmUserEntry localSnmpID snmpv3user usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol usmDESPrivProtocol nonVolatile coROopsTransTag "md5pass" "despass"
usmUserEntry localSnmpID snmpv3ops usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol usmAesCfb128Protocol nonVolatile coROopsTransTag "opsauth" "opspriv"
usmUserEntry localSnmpID snmpv3dev usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol usmAesCfb128Protocol nonVolatile coROopsTransTag "devauth" "devpriv"    
#
## SOME STUFF HERE
#
blablabla
```

### Shell script `addline.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

CIAGT_CNF=./snmpd.cnf
Username=FooDoe
AuthPasswd=A^thP@swd
EncrKey=3ncrKev

getLine() {
    section=0
    currentline=0
    prevline=0
    while read line; do
        echo "$line" | grep -q "$1"
        if [ $? -eq 0  ]; then
            section=1
            continue
        fi
        echo "$line" | grep -q -v "^#"
        ret=$?
        if [ $ret -eq 0  -a $section -eq 1 ]; then
            currentline=`grep -n "^$line" $CIAGT_CNF | cut -f1 -d":"`
            break
        fi
        echo
    done < $CIAGT_CNF
    prevline=`expr $currentline - 1 `
}

UserEntry() {
    sed "/^usmUserEntry localSnmpID /d" $CIAGT_CNF > /tmp/sed$$
    cat /tmp/sed$$ > $CIAGT_CNF && rm /tmp/sed$$

    ## Calling getLine() from within UserEntry() DID NOT work (was returning all lines)
    ## getLine "^# Entry type: usmUserEntry"

    ## sed "${prevline}a\        ## Uncomment this if you call getLine() above
    sed "${1}a\
    usmUserEntry localSnmpID $Username usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol usmAesCfb128Protocol nonVolatile coROopsTransTag \"$AuthPasswd\" \"$EncrKey\"\\
    usmUserEntry localSnmpID public usmNoAuthProtocol usmNoPrivProtocol nonVolatile coROopsTransTag - -" $CIAGT_CNF > /tmp/sed$$
    cat /tmp/sed$$ > $CIAGT_CNF
}

## MAIN

## Method 1
## NOTE: Uncomment "getline ..." in UserEntry()
## Calling getLine() from within UserEntry() DID NOT work (was returning all lines)...
## UserEntry

## Method 2 (workaround)
## ... so we have to call getLine() first and then UserEntry() passing the value of
## $prevline as a parameter
getLine "^# Entry type: usmUserEntry"
UserEntry $prevline
```

Comment: tl;dr -- Too much extraneous detail. reduce your example to show the problem you describe. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @glennjackman: I think the example is pretty minimal for someone to understand the problem and reproduce it himself.
Do you have a solution to this issue or any other constructive comment ?

Comment: The code is not minimal.  It contains acres of comments.  The data is more complex than necessary to reproduce the problem, too.  You should aim to avoid the scrollbars — both horizontal and vertical.  You can't always manage it, but you often can.

Comment: You may try your example in a fresh directory before giving us: for instance `CIAGT_CNF=/tmp/snmpd.cnf` should be set to `./snmpd.cnf`, remove the first `cp`, remove path from `sed` (we have not the same). Tx

Comment: Alright, I think this is the absolute necessary to understand and reproduce the issue.
In any case, thanks for your comments. First time here...

Comment: For me both work the same. Your code is horrible (no offense), I don't want to look further into it. You didn't even tell what you're trying to achieve—there sure are much better ways to proceed. You tagged your question _Bash_, yet your script has an `sh` shebang (FYI, Bash≠sh). Sorry for being so negative.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I guess you are focusing too much on your negativity that you failed to read what I wrote at the very top: "My ultimate goal is to processes a configuration file and add an entry at a specific place in the file"...
I take no offense but if you wanna make a negative comment, you should also be able to provide another (or better) solution!
So, do you have to contribute anything?

p.s. FYI, #!/bin/sh is a symlink to bash in openSUSE, SLES and other Linux distros, thus the tag "bash".

Comment: One thing I can ask about something that looks very awkward to me (but I doubt it'll change anything to your problem): what do you think the line `ret=$?` in the function `getLine` does? I'm pretty sure you're mistaken on this point.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: You are right. There was a line which I accidentally deleted when previous people commented that I should reduce my code... Now it's there!

So, do you understand what I want to achieve?

Comment: I edited your post to have your code with better indentation. I hope you don't mind. (I also added some quotes in the lines `echo "$line"`, they looked too ugly without `:D`.

Comment: By the way, you should definitely initialize the variable `currentline` in the function `getLine`.

Comment: Sure, no problem about editing the post... I'll initialize `currentline` and I'll try it, but I don't think this is the problem...

Comment: So with Method 1, when you call `userEntry`, the first `sed` deletes some lines… and I guess that the lines that are deleted are the lines that `getLine` is trying to find.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with function calls from within a function. Your problem is just a logic problem. I'd advise you to use `set -x` in your scripts when debugging.

Comment: Please, in both methods insert a debugging line just before the sed command in the UserEntry function: ***echo "prevline: $prevline"***. And post here the values of the displayed prevline variable

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Method 1 calls `UserEntry` which deletes some entries in the configuration file. Then, from within `UserEntry` I call `getLine` in order to find the section and the exact line number where I want to add a NEW entry. The `getLine` should supposedly return a line number to `UserEntry` that is then used by `sed ${prevline}a\...` to add the NEW entries after that line. However things get messy after the last line (that has comments) is read.

Comment: @jdamian: I had quite a few debugging info in the code, which was not liked by many readers as they thought it was getting complicated.
You can get the original script here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16344489/Code/addline.sh and the config file I'm working on here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16344489/Code/snmpd.cnf.ORIG

Just put them in your home dir and execute it from there.

Comment: @Yannis, some suggestions to improve your code: why do you use the grep command to find out the file line number? -- You are using a loop to read line by line; therefore you only need a counter to find out the current line number.

Comment: @Jdamian: Essentially what I want to do is to insert some entries in a specific section in a configuration file. How do you suggest I should do it?

Comment: @Yannis: I have no objection to your method -- I just thought the use of *** grep|cut *** inside the getLine is unnecessary. The *** grep|cut *** line may be supressed if your first line inside the loop is: ***currentline=``expr $currentline + 1``***

Comment: I think you overlooked my previous comment, so here it is again: **with Method 1, when you call userEntry, the first sed deletes some lines… and the lines that are deleted are the lines that getLine is trying to find.** I'm positive about this.

Comment: It's just that _the order in which you're calling the commands is important_ and you're not respecting that.

Comment: Also, I never read what you said about sh being symlinked to bash (maybe you edited the comment after I read it). So, for your information, you will find in the manual that `If bash is invoked with the name sh, it  tries  to  mimic  the  startup behavior  of  historical  versions  of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.` So your question is about `sh` and not about `bash`.

Comment: You keep on making marginal edits, but your question would require a complete overhaul.  The title does not appear to reflect the problem you are actually asking about, and the script you use to show the problem has a number of independent problems, to the point where any decent answer would end up rewriting the script substantially, with guesses about your requirements and environment.  I have downvoted and nominated to close, and I don't think any amount of incremental edits can sway my opinion on those two points.  Please review the material behind the help link in the footer of this page.

Comment: So far, everyone is making generic comments like "Your code is horrible" or "the script you use to show the problem has a number of independent problems" or I have the wrong title, but NOBODY has made actually any REAL contribution except @Jdamian who provided a tip that solved part of my problem! My requirement is stated clearly on the very top of my question. My environment is SLES 11 and openSUSE 13.1. For those who keep on arguing whether my question is about `sh` or `bash`, I've tried with different shells and had the same result. Honestly, I was expecting more from the community...

Comment: Yannis, please read (and understand) my comments. What I previously wrote in bold shows why your code doesn't work. Period.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I did read your comment and understood it.
`UserEntry` deletes all lines starting with `usmUserEntry localSnmpID` in the config file. Then `getLine` is called with the argument `"^# Entry type: usmUserEntry"` which basically finds the line starting with `" Entry type: usmUserEntry" and once it finds it, calculates how many lines are commented after this line so to write a custom entry after the last commented line.
Both functions work fine when called individually from the main script. It's when `getLine` is called from within `UserEntry` when there is an issue.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: If you have time please download the original script here: dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16344489/Code/addline.sh and the config file I'm working on here: dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16344489/Code/snmpd.cnf.ORIG which contain a few debugging info throughout the code.

Comment: @Jdamian: Thank you very much for your suggestion of `currentline=expr $currentline + 1` which actually did the trick as a workaround and for your code. I didn't think to use `read` this way...
While your code inserts a pair of lines just before the first line starting with `usmUserEntry localSnmpID` how could I add some lines just after the last commented line (I wouldn't know how many commented lines are there) of the section which starts with `# Entry type: usmUserEntry`. ?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: To avoid excessive comments here, I can be contacted at techie@unimad.net. Thanks.

Comment: @Jdamian: : To avoid excessive comments here, I can be contacted at techie@unimad.net. Thanks!

Comment: @Jdamian: You rock! Thanks a million!
In the `if   [ "${f1} ${f2} {f3} {f4}"` I suppose you meant `if   [ "${f1} ${f2} ${f3} ${f4}"`. I also removed the `\042` and replaced it with `\"` as in the particular case of `$EncrKey` (EncrKey=3ncrKev) it was translated to `\043ncrKev` and would display a strange character. Approve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have my bash code. It inserts a pair of lines just before the first line starting with `usmUserEntry localSnmpID`. All other lines from config file `$CIAGT_CNF` are copied to `/tmp/sed$$` file

```
typeset -i inserted=0
while read line
do
     read f1 f2 _ <<<"${line}"

     if   [ "${f1}${f2}" = usmUserEntrylocalSnmpID ]
     then
          if   [ "$inserted" -eq 0 ]
          then
               echo "
usmUserEntry localSnmpID $Username usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol usmAesCfb128Protocol nonVolatile coROopsTransTag \042$AuthPasswd\042 \042$EncrKey\042
usmUserEntry localSnmpID public usmNoAuthProtocol usmNoPrivProtocol nonVolatile coROopsTransTag - -
"
               inserted=1
          fi
     fi
     # Prints the original text line 
     echo "$line"
done < "$CIAGT_CNF" > /tmp/sed$$
```

UPDATE: 2014-11-06

```
typeset -i inserted=0
while read line
do
     read f1 f2 f3 f4 _ <<<"${line}"

     if   [ "${f1} ${f2} ${f3} ${f4}" = "# Entry type: usmUserEntry" ]
     then
          echo "$line"

          # Read and print every line starting with '#'
          while read line
          do
               read f1 _ <<<"${line}"
               if   [ "${f1#'#'}" = "${f1}" ]
               then
                    # Exit the inner loop When the first
                    # non-starting '#' line is found.

                    break
               fi
               echo "$line"
          done

          if   [ "$inserted" -eq 0 ]
          then
               echo "
usmUserEntry localSnmpID $Username usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol usmAesCfb128Protocol nonVolatile coROopsTransTag \042$AuthPasswd\042 \042$EncrKey\042
usmUserEntry localSnmpID public usmNoAuthProtocol usmNoPrivProtocol nonVolatile coROopsTransTag - -
"
               inserted=1
          fi
     fi

     # Prints the original text line 
     echo "$line"
done < "$CIAGT_CNF" > /tmp/sed$$
```

Best regards